# Unable to start gunicorn.service due to import module error

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, systemd

I am trying to start Gunicorn from systemd service file, but I get import module error. How can I fix it?

My gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myproject
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I execute `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application`, there is no error.

But when I use

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Improved formatting, stated issue in begging of post

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a directory permission problem.  Make sure the user sammy is in the www-data group and set the home directory permissions with a chmod 710.